# Windows 7 SP1 Not Able To Run Windows Update Error 80070002

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I've been having this problem for awhile.  Windows 7 SP1 Not Able To Run Windows Update Error 80070002.  I've run Troubleshooter but it just continues to glow scroll.  Cannot download any newer updates either.  Update history says that I have never applied any updates.

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-update-error-80070002#1TC=windows-7

Comment: http://superuser.com/search?q=80070002

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [this Microsoft article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-update-error-80070002#1TC=windows-7), the Windows Update temporary files need to be removed. Follow the steps there, or do the following if you prefer the command line:

Open an administrative command prompt by pressing the Start button, typing "cmd", right-clicking the result, and choosing "Run as administrator." Type the following commands, pressing Enter after each:

1. `sc stop wuauserv` to stop the Windows Update service
2. `cd \Windows\SoftwareDistribution` to navigate to the Windows Update folder
3. `rmdir /s /q DataStore` to remove the DataStore folder
4. `rmdir /s /q Download` to remove the Download folder
5. `md DataStore` to recreate an empty DataStore folder
6. `md Download` to recreate an empty Download folder
7. `sc start wuauserv` to resume the Windows Update service

Close the command prompt and try to use Windows Update again.