# Windows 10 update Error code 80070002

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade my Windows 7 Ultimate to Windows 10.
Since I don't get my notification and don't see any updates on Windows Update I'm trying to force the upgrade.
I read on reddit that you can go to the registry and add `AllowOSUpgrade` as a DWORD with the value of `1` to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\OSUpgrade`

So I tried that and when I check for updates it tells me Windows 10 is ready and I press `Get Started`. It downloads the 2605MB file, then it says "preparing for installation", then it gives the following error:
[image: Error code 80070002]

I tried this: [Windows 7 SP1 Not Able To Run Windows Update Error 80070002](https://superuser.com/questions/944071/windows-7-sp1-not-able-to-run-windows-update-error-80070002)
It deleted my history and the download, so I checked for updates again, pressed "Get Started" and the problem happened again.

What do I do now?

P.S. I also tried updating via the "Media Creation Tool" from Microsoft's website. It downloads everything, asks me what to save, then it says it wants to make sure I have enough space. Then it stops with an error that says something like: "couldn't make sure you have enough space on your PC", even though I have 180GB free on my only hard drive.

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: [Perform a clean Boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135) then try upgrade in a clean boot state.

Comment: 80070002 = file not found. Have you moved system folder away from C:\ to a different drive?

Comment: Mine seems to get as far as rebooting into the installer, and around 13% done, 46% of the way into copying files, restarts and the goes into "restoring your previous OS". This is with Windows 8.1 on a system with around 160Gb free space. The FAQ suggests only 8Gb free space is needed.

Comment: I tried following these steps - http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/windows-update-error-80070002#1TC=windows-7 - which didn't help me either. I am going to now attempt a clean boot tomorrow - as 3 attempts today is quite enough for now.

Comment: Perhaps some driver or service that windows is trying to update isn't a base component, is demanded by the update, but not included in the update. Would there be more detail in event viewer or a log for it?

Comment: Having a go again now - and failing that - this may then be useful: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/902093

Comment: Ok - not clean boot issue - same place - 13% done, 46% files done. Same error code 80070002-20007.

Comment: Ah wait - you've forced the update - which is quite different from my situation - however, I think trying the media creation tool should be my next step.

Answer (score 2):

There is a help page for this specific issue:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-update-error-80070002#1TC=windows-7

> If you receive Windows Update error 80070002 while checking for updates, you need to remove the temporary update files that Windows uses to identify updates for your computer. To remove the temporary files, stop the Windows Update service, delete the temporary update files, restart the Windows Update service, and then try to check for Windows updates again.

Click to open each line for an extensive step-by-step process to resolve.